# Unity freezes when destroying all children

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a paint brush that writes on the screen by instantiating many sprite dots into a parent `GameObject`.

I want to clear all the sprite dots with a click of a button. There could be up to 50 but when I clear them Unity freezes. The code seems right.

```
public void ClearPaint()
{
    while (paintDrawing.transform.childCount > 0)
    {
        Destroy(paintDrawing.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: How long does it freeze for?

Comment: Are `paintDrawing` and `chalkWriting` the same node?

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake posting the question. It should be all `paintDrawing`

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but you might want to use object pooling, creating and destroying many objects per frame is a performance sink anyways. https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/object-pooling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects are not destroyed immediately, Unity waits at least until the current Update loop ends.

> [Object.Destroy](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html): The object obj will be destroyed now or if a time is specified t seconds from now. If obj is a Component it will remove the component from the GameObject and destroy it. If obj is a GameObject it will destroy the GameObject, all its components and all transform children of the GameObject. Actual object destruction is always delayed until after the current Update loop, but will always be done before rendering.

You could use [Object.DestroyImmediate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DestroyImmediate.html), but that will cause lags too.

Best practice is to deactivate the object prior destroying:

```
public void ClearPaint()
{
    for (Transform child in transform) {
        child.gameObject.SetActive(false);  
        Destroy(child.gameObject);            
    }
}
```

If this is a recent activity, you could also consider reusing the GameObjects with [pooling](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/object-pooling).

Edit: Fixed code and typos

Comment: thanks for that. All makes sense. Unfortunately it is not entering into the `for` loop. `Debug.Log(children.Length);` gives me 27 so it is getting the children. If I put a `Debug.Log("inside for"); I get nothing

Answer (score 2):

You destroy children from chalkWriting but you check count on paintDrawing. So you have an infinite loop.

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake posting the question. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the childcount doesn't get updated when you destroy one. I personally try to stay away from while loops that could go on infinitely in Unity. I would try something like this:

```
public void ClearPaint()
{
    Transform[] children = paintDrawing.transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
    for(int i = 0; i > children.Length; i++) {
        Destroy(children[i].gameObject);            
    }
}
```